# jQuery: prompt user when attempting to refresh or close browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Scenario: I have a web app that i will let user 1 to set some values in the form (`#div1`) and display it to the next user (who comes to the browser after user 1 without closing the browser) (the display will be shown in `#div2` while `#div1` will be hidden). However if user 2 refresh the browser, all the values will be gone.

Question: How can i alert the user when he attempts to refresh the browser? the web app will be on `Midori` and the web server is `CherryPy`.

Or is there a way to save the session regardless of the refresh? and how?

Comment: What do you mean, "to the next user"? I really don't understand what is happening here...

Comment: just save it in the session. as long as there is no destroying of session ur values will be saved.

Comment: @Amadan that was just a scenario. please see the edit :) hope that explains :) or do u prefer the whole story?

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! :D thank you. but the prompt that it gave me was "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

You need to use `onbeforeunload`. Basically, if you application is in "busy" state you set the handler which will ask the user if he/she really wants to leave ;)

Answer (score 2):

You've asked two questions.

To the first, "How can i alert the user when he attempts to refresh the browser?":

In a `beforeunload` function, include the following (with whatever text you want, obviously):

```
confirm('If you refresh the page your data will be lost');
```

This will create an alert with 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons.  If the user presses 'OK', the page continues with what it was doing (in your case, refreshing); otherwise, it returns false.

To the second question, "Or is there a way to save the session regardless of the refresh?":  Yes.

**Edit:** You've now asked a third question, "How?" But that's really beyond the scope of StackOverflow's question-answer format.  The quick answer is that there are several ways, including cookies and DOM storage and using the back end.  Try one out, and if you run into problems ask specific questions and we'll help.

Comment: I guess he is asking how to show this confirm box on page refresh or reload?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer :) +1 and sorry for the question edit :s anyway, still thank you for the quick answer. will research more on those mentioned by you before asking further :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var message = "Are you sure you want to leave?";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = message;     
  return message;                                
});
```

For the second part of your question, there are several options. Probably the simplest is localStorage:

```
// after form updated
if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined') {
  localStorage.formData = formData // where formData is a string containing all the data from the form
}

// on page load (e.g. after refresh)
if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined') {
  populateForm(localStorage.formData); // where populateForm is a function that can take the string you saved and does what you want with it (sorry, I didn't really understand that part of the question)
}
```

Comment: *Should* work, but did you actually try it?  I did (copied from MDN like I'm sure you did) and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in Chrome - which browser are you using?